# Animation of jQuery SlideToggle changes by adding a height (%)

Tags: jquery, html, css

The code below runs a **jQuery SlideToggle** menu. Once you click on the `<container>` the `<panel>` is scrolled out. This all works fine so far.

However, now I want to assign a **relative** `height: 25%;` to the `<div>` inside the `<panel>`. 
 *(see comments in my CSS below)* 
  Once I do this the **animation** of the SlideToggle **changes** and scrolls in the `<panel>` differently.

How can I add a relative `height: 25%;` so the animation **remains** the **same** as without the relative height?

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p6dqLLj6/65/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

```css
html { 
height: 100%; 
}

body { 
height: 100%; 
}

.container {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.panel {
  height: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.panel div {
  height: 25%; /* Why does the animation change by adding this height? */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">Menu</div> 
    
<div class="panel">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by animation change? How it is changing.

Comment: Hi Sanchit Patiyal, the problem is that it is very difficult to explain in words, therefore, I put the https://jsfiddle.net/p6dqLLj6/65/ to my question so you can run the code once without the 25% and once including the 25% and then you see the difference. With the 25% it looks like the <div> inside the <panel> is scrolled in as well whereas without the 25% the <div> inside the <panel> already exists in the right size.

Comment: Give a static height in pix and it will work fine. I added changes in fiddle also

Comment: @Michi, When you are using 25% height, as the container .panel starts getting smaller, all the div inside start to re-arrange themselves at 25% of container, as it keeps getting smaller. When you remove height 25%, it doesn't do that. That's why animations change.

Comment: I mainly use the 25% so I can be sure the children completely fill the height of the parent and there is no empty space or anything. I also tried to do it with the display: flex property here https://jsfiddle.net/kyva8mhe/22/ but could not make it work either. I know the fixed height solves the animation issue but on the other side it brings the space problem. However, it seems there is no solution to combine the both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use a % value, the problem is that while the panel is shrinking the height still takes the 25%, that's why you see that effect, if you put a static height is working correctly..

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

```css
html { 
height: 100%; 
}

body { 
height: 100%; 
}

.container {
  height: 115px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.panel {
  height: 115px;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.panel div {/* Why does the animation change by adding this height? */
    /*height:25%;*/
    height: 28.4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">Menu</div> 
    
<div class="panel">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi RenzoCC, thanks a lot for your answer. I mainly use the 25% so I can be sure the children completely fill the height of the parent and there is no empty space or anything. I also tried to do it with the display: flex property here https://jsfiddle.net/kyva8mhe/22/ but could not make it work. I know the fixed height solves the animation issue but on the other side it brings the space problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/p6dqLLj6/68/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
    }).css({
     height: $('.panel').height()
    });
    
    $(window).resize( function(){
     $(".container").css({
        height: $('.panel').height()
      });
    });
});
```

```css
html { 
  height: 100%; 
}

body { 
  height: 100%; 
}

.container {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.panel {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.panel div {
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">Menu</div> 
    
<div class="panel">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```

I'm calculating the height of `.container` div based on the height of `.panel` div using `jQuery`, also added feature of resize height of `.container` div on resizing window.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Shiladitya, thanks for your answer. I guess I was not clear enough in my question but my goal is not that the <panel> has the same size of the <container>. My goal is that I can apply a relative height to the <div> inside the <panel> so I can adjust the height of the <div> so they fit exactly inside the <panel>. Eventually, the perfect version would be that I have a relative height for each container so I have a high flexibility in adjusting something on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use display flex we can add multi column and you get the same height for each column

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").on('click', function () {
    console.log(this);
       
        $( "div" ).find('.panel').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

```css
html { 
height: 100%; 
}

body { 
height: 100%; 
}
.main{display:flex;width:100%}
.container {
  flex:1;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.flex-4 {
  flex:4;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.panel{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.panel div {
   flex:1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

<div class="container">Menu</div> 
 <div class="flex-4">   
<div class="panel">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

or check the code from here [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rida_zd/38tm6egt/)