# GetElementBy only works with ID not with classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

With code below I want to insert some `<content>` once the user clicks on the `<button>`.

Before I went with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9bc2fyen/3/) code which was working totally fine. Then I changed the `id="content"` to `class="content"` and the `document.getElementById` of the **JavaScript** code to `getElementsByClassName` and now the function is not working anymore.

What do I have to change my code so it also works with classes?

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9mj4ho2k/).

```js
window.myFunction = function () {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.content {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10%
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Button</button>

<div class="content">
Content of element
</div>
```

Comment: change `ClassName()[0]` beacuse the classname is the  multiple selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getElementsByClassName`

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names.

For more info please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). For this reason you have to get the first element of your array, in order to have the same result. You can access it by using the index of 0.

```js
window.myFunction = function () {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.content {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10%
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Button</button>

<div class="content">
Content of element
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Christos, thanks a lot for this fast answer. What does the [0] exactly mean?

Comment: I have also updated it here https://jsfiddle.net/9mj4ho2k/1/.

Comment: @Michi Ah ok, understood :)

Comment: As you can see by @Michi code getElementsByClassName returns an array. You may want to check out document.querySelector to avoid dealing with an array when using classes to identify unique elements.

Comment: @DaleCorns Indeed mate, it can be used `document.querySelector`, in order to solve this problem. However, I wanted to show why  `document.getElementsByClassName` didn't work in they that this method hd been used by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do this is:

`var x = document.querySelector(".content");`

Comment: Hi Punit Gupta, in which why is it better then the getElementsByClassName method? I am a newbie and looking forward to some expert advice :-)

Comment: `querySelector` method can be used to refer to any DOM element with any  simple as well as complex CSS selector. While it is perfectly okay to use `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` for single id or single className, `querySelector` can deal with cases like, '.content div' or '.content p', when you want to get a sub-tag under a class or id.

Comment: @Michi You can find expert advice using the "Google" search engine which will point you to hundreds and thousands of tutorials, intros, documentation pages, and blog posts.

Answer (score 2):

You have different methods available in native javascript (for those not using jquery) to get any element on the page. 
 These are

1. document.querySelectorAll()

   `document.querySelectorAll("div.classNameOne, div.classNameTwo");`
2. document.querySelector(selector)

   `document.querySelector("div.className")`
3. document.getElementById(idname of element)

   `document.getElementById("element_id")`
4. document.getElementsByTagName(tagname - get all div or span on page)

   `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`
5. document.getElementsByClassName(classname - get all elements with specific class name)

   `document.getElementsByClassName("your_css_class_name")`
6. You can also get any attribute of element by

   `document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].getAttribute("class");`

When it returns multiple elements, it returns them like an array. You can index them using an indexer starting from 0.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your answer and the advice. By the way, are there still a lot of people using jQuery or is it "outdated"?

Comment: No, jquery isn't outdated, nor is javascript. What I meant was people generally use lot of jquery for element selection kind of things.

Comment: It's very hard to support the notion that jQuery is not outdated, looking at any metric of usage and adoption.

Comment: Simple graph. Lot of them use it still.  https://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/jQuery

Comment: Do you also have any idea how to solve this issue here with the relative heights or if it is even possible to do it with relative heights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862637/animation-of-jquery-slidetoggle-changes-by-adding-a-height

Comment: @Michi, I have added my comment on the question.